# Puppeteer not running on dedicated GPU

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, puppeteer, nvidia, babylonjs

I'm trying to get this to work.
My setup is a Ubuntu 18.04 with two graphic cards, one is onboard, the other one is a NVIDIA GPU. I have a monitor connected and the $DISPLAY is set to :0
My application is to take automated screenshots from webgl-context (BABYLON.js) webpages automatically using puppeteer headless using node-js.
The hardware is running in our datacenter and the onboard GPU is physically conntected to a supervision tool that our admins use.

However, regardless of what I do I cannot make puppeteer/chromium build up a context on the nvidia GPU, it seems to only use the the onboard-GPU for everything.

My way of trying this is by running this code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ['--use-gl=desktop'],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page
        .goto('https://codepen.io/BabylonJS/pen/QxzBPd', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 20 * 60 * 1000 })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    await page.screenshot({
        path: 'webgl_test.png'
    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

I get a rendered output, however it does not seem to use the nvidia GPU for that as the nvidia-smi which I monitor by using `watch -n 0.1 nvidia-smi` did not show any process running.

Is there any way to force puppeteer to use the GPU for rendering the page? Or is it more that I'd have to create a X-Server on this GPU first?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Chromium#Force_GPU_acceleration You can try to refer to the above documentation configuration, I also encountered the same problem, is still in the stage of installing OpenGL

Comment: ~/.config/chromium-flags.conf
--ignore-gpu-blocklist
--enable-gpu-rasterization
--enable-zero-copy Those Flags seem to be interesting.